# issue in reading objects from LinkedList in java

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Bankapp {
        public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException   {
        String file="C:\\Users\\RaviKiran Reddy\\Desktop\\JBNR\\NewBankAccounts.csv";
        List<String[]> newAccounts=Csv.read(file);
        List<Account> openedaccounts=new LinkedList<Account>();
        for(String[] accountholdersdata:newAccounts) { 
            String name=accountholdersdata[0];
            String Ssn=accountholdersdata[1];
            String acctype=accountholdersdata[2];
            double initial_deposit=Double.parseDouble(accountholdersdata[3]);
             if(acctype=="Checking")
        openedaccounts.add(new Checking(name,Ssn,acctype,initial_deposit));
             else
              openedaccounts.add(new Savings(name,Ssn,acctype,initial_deposit));
        }
      ObjectOutputStream out=new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("records.txt"));
      out.writeObject(opaccounts);
      ObjectInputStream in=new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("records.txt"));
    LinkedList<Account> a=new LinkedList<Account>();
      a=(LinkedList<Account>)in.readObject();
      for(int i=0;i<openedaccounts.size();i++) {
          a.get(i).showInfo();// showInfo is a method used to display the account information
      }
      }
}
```

when I try to store and read objects from the above code I am getting the error message as:

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.io.InvalidClassException: bankaccountapp.Savings; no valid constructor
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass$ExceptionInfo.newInvalidClassException(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.checkDeserialize(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedList.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at bankaccountapp.Bankapp.main(Bankapp.java:26)".
```

could anyone help me with this.

```
    package bankaccountapp;
    import java.lang.String;;

    public abstract class Account {
        private String name;
        private String Ssn;
        private String AccType;
        private String Accountnumb;
        private static int unique=10000;
        int rand_numb=(int)(Math.random()*Math.pow(10,2));
        private double Accbalance;
        public Account(String name,String Ssn,String AccType,double initial_deposit) {
            unique++;
            this.name=name;
            this.Ssn=Ssn;
            this.AccType=AccType;
            this.Accbalance=initial_deposit;
            Accountnumb=unique+""+rand_numb+""+Ssn.substring(7,9);
            }

        public void deposit(int amount) {
            Accbalance=Accbalance+amount;
            System.out.println("your Account balance is:  "+Accbalance);
            }

        public void withdraw(int amount) {
            Accbalance=Accbalance-amount;
            System.out.println("your remaining balance is:   "+Accbalance);
            }

        public void showInfo() {
            System.out.println("***************");
            System.out.println("Name:  "+name+"\n"+ "Accountmunber:  "+Accountnumb+"\n"+"Acctype:  "+AccType+"\n"+"Accountbalance:  "+""+Accbalance);
            }
            }
```

checking class:

package bankaccountapp;

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Checking extends Account implements Serializable {

int debitcard;
int pin; 

    public Checking(String name, String Ssn, String AccType,double initdeposit) {
        super(name, Ssn, AccType, initdeposit);
         debitcard=(int)(Math.random()*Math.pow(10, 11));
         pin=(int)(Math.random()*Math.pow(10,4));
    }

    public void showInfo() {
        super.showInfo();
        System.out.println("Debitcard:"+debitcard+"\n"+"Pin:"+pin);
    }
}
```

savings class:

```
package bankaccountapp;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Savings extends Account implements Serializable{

    public Savings(String name, String Ssn, String AccType,double initdeposit) {
        super(name, Ssn, AccType, initdeposit);

    }

        public void showInfo() {
            super.showInfo();;
        }
    }
```

Above is my Account(which is an abstract class) class coding.
Hope this will be helpful in understanding my issue.
Above is my Account(which is an abstract class) class coding.
Hope this will be helpful in understanding my issue.

Comment: Please take the time to correctly format your code before posting.

Comment: Unrelated to your question: `if(acctype=="Checking")`. This is **not** the right way to check strings equality.  Strings are **objects** and should be normally compared through `equals()`.

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score 0):

The class you are trying to serialize must have a no-arg constructor.  I'm not absolutely sure this is the answer because your code is kind of wall-of-textish and I don't think it contains the definition of the class you are serializing (Account?), but that's the usual cause of the error you listed.

EDIT: RE: new code

As I figured above, Account does not have a no-args constructor.

Add a constructor that looks like this:

public Account(){}

and it should work.  Add this kind of constructor to any class you intend to serialize.  This is a requirement of serialization since Java has no clue how to create the objects to pass to your constructor... Instead it calls the no-arg constructor above and then initializes all the members to their previous value.

Comment: I will add them in my question.

Comment: thanks, i have added all my code in the question now. could you have a look at it.